# How to run java node via launch file?

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
How can we include java node in launch file? I know we normally include roscpp and rospy nodes in launch files but how to include such following command in lauch file e.g:
rosrun rosjava_bootstrap run.py java_package java_node __name:=j_node
Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33410/how-to-run-java-node-via-launch-file?/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best option currently is to use the installApp task to build an executable jar and wrapper script (see the rosjava_tutorial_pubsub example and the rosjava_core documentation: http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html). Then you can use roslaunch to execute it in the same way you would an arbitrary executable.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-05-10**:
Thanks. I have a topic t1 which bublishes strings "yes" and sometimes "no". Another topic t2 publishes string "why" only when t1 bublishes "no". Now I want to get a chart/graph. When and which topic triggered. I have seen the rxplot (only works for numeric values). rxconsole gives the output but in a seraial form. Is there any way you know how to get my desired plot OR how to get a text file from rxconsole so that i can play with in Matlab to get the plot. I mean I am only interested triggering of the topic but on some specific values. Regards and thanks in advance

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-05-20**:
@safzam This is a separate question.  Please ask it separately.